# "Fit All in Window" using JavaScript

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, javascript

I've recently started scripting in Illustrator and having a little problem. When creating a document through File tab, (File->New, Print, Letter) the created document is positioned at `(0,0)` and the view is focused on the document.

But if I create a document using JS, for example `app.documents.add();`, the created document isn't positioned at `(0,0)`, but at `(0,-792)`. I reposition the artboard and move it to `(0,0)` with `app.activeDocument.artboards[0].artboardRect = [0, 0, 612, -792];`. This moves the artboard below, out of the view. I need to scroll down to get the artboard into view.

Is there a way to focus the view on the artboard using JS? Maybe call the "Fit All in Window" command?

If there isn't a quick fix, I'll have to do this the hard way, code it myself.

Comment: It's because the coordinate system is different in scripting, the bottom left of your artboard is at 0,0. Is there a reason you need it different?

Comment: I'm well aware of that. I'm creating multiple artboards depending on the images in a folder, and filling the artboards with them. Using a "different" coordinate system complicates the process of position calculation for the artboards and the images. I'm already working on a script version of "Fit All on Window" command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been told [<sup>[*]</sup>](https://forums.adobe.com/message/8997757) that there is a built-in way to do this:

```
app.executeMenuCommand("fitall");
```

but I've created a JS version of the command anyway.

["Fit All in Window" command for Illustrator in JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/akinuri/069df4320fbfb05cb00bae0b588e4b7e)

```
function calcRect(rectArray) {
    var rect = {
        rect  : rectArray.join(", "),
        topLeft    : {
            x : rectArray[0],
            y : rectArray[1],
        },
        bottomRight    : {
            x : rectArray[2],
            y : rectArray[3],
        },
    };
    rect.width  = Math.abs(rect.bottomRight.x - rect.topLeft.x);
    rect.height = Math.abs(rect.bottomRight.y - rect.topLeft.y);
    rect.center = [
        rect.topLeft.x + (rect.width / 2),
        rect.topLeft.y - (rect.height / 2)
    ];
    rect.aspectRatio = rect.width / rect.height;
    return rect;
}

function calcViewRect(rectArray, zoom) {
    var rect = {
        rect  : rectArray.join(", "),
        topLeft    : {
            x : rectArray[0],
            y : rectArray[1],
        },
        bottomRight    : {
            x : rectArray[2],
            y : rectArray[3],
        },
    };
    rect.width        = Math.abs(rect.bottomRight.x - rect.topLeft.x);
    rect.height       = Math.abs(rect.bottomRight.y - rect.topLeft.y);
    rect.zoom         = zoom || 1;
    rect.actualWidth  = rect.width * zoom;
    rect.actualHeight = rect.height * zoom;
    rect.aspectRatio  = rect.width / rect.height;
    return rect;
}

function getDocumentBounds(artboards) {
    var rect = {
        topLeft : {
            x : null,
            y : null,
        },
        bottomRight : {
            x : null,
            y : null,
        },
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < artboards.length; i++) {
        var artboardRect = calcRect(artboards[i].artboardRect);

        if (rect.topLeft.x == null) {
            rect.topLeft.x = artboardRect.topLeft.x;
        } else {
            if (artboardRect.topLeft.x < rect.topLeft.x) {
                rect.topLeft.x = artboardRect.topLeft.x;
            }
        }

        if (rect.topLeft.y == null) {
            rect.topLeft.y = artboardRect.topLeft.y;
        } else {
            if (artboardRect.topLeft.y > rect.topLeft.y) {
                rect.topLeft.y = artboardRect.topLeft.y;
            }
        }

        if (rect.bottomRight.x == null) {
            rect.bottomRight.x = artboardRect.bottomRight.x;
        } else {
            if (artboardRect.bottomRight.x > rect.bottomRight.x) {
                rect.bottomRight.x = artboardRect.bottomRight.x;
            }
        }

        if (rect.bottomRight.y == null) {
            rect.bottomRight.y = artboardRect.bottomRight.y;
        } else {
            if (artboardRect.bottomRight.y < rect.bottomRight.y) {
                rect.bottomRight.y = artboardRect.bottomRight.y;
            }
        }
    }
    rect.rect = [rect.topLeft.x, rect.topLeft.y, rect.bottomRight.x, rect.bottomRight.y];
    return rect;
}

function calcZoom(viewRect, documentRect, margin) {
    if (documentRect.aspectRatio > viewRect.aspectRatio) {
        return parseFloat(((viewRect.actualWidth - (2 * margin)) / documentRect.width).toFixed(2));
    } else {
        return parseFloat(((viewRect.actualHeight - (2 * margin)) / documentRect.height).toFixed(2));
    }
}

function fitAll(document) {
    var view         = document.views[0];

    var viewRect     = calcViewRect(view.bounds, view.zoom);
    var documentRect = calcRect(getDocumentBounds(document.artboards).rect);

    view.centerPoint = documentRect.center;
    view.zoom        = calcZoom(viewRect, documentRect, 20);
}

// fitAll(app.activeDocument);
```

Answer (score 0):

I lucked onto another possible solution that seemed to work for me, at least once.

```
app.executeMenuCommand("fitall");
```

This is a very poorly documented set of functions best described here:

[JS] CS6+ executeMenuCommand
https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/js-cs6-executemenucommand/td-p/5904747?page=1#6114502

Comment: What new info do you bring to the table?